# How to parse and update column value in T- SQL using IF ELSE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Based on a substring in **DECRIPTION** I want to assign value to another column.
Example there is a substring in DECRIPTION column **( rety #WA# hskhkhsd)**, now I will check for **#WA#**. If present I will assign **WrongAnswer** in a new column **Short_Code_Detail**.
I tried doing it using `LIKE` but I want to try with `IF ELSE` as well.

```
SELECT
       [ID]
      ,[DECRIPTION]
      ,CASE
        WHEN DECRIPTION LIKE '%#WR#%' THEN 'Wrong Routine'
        WHEN DECRIPTION LIKE '%#RB#%' THEN 'Received Band'
        WHEN DECRIPTION LIKE '%#WA#%' THEN 'Week A'
        WHEN DECRIPTION LIKE '%#CP#%' THEN 'Change P'
        WHEN DECRIPTION LIKE '%#BQ#%' THEN 'Bad Q'
        WHEN DECRIPTION LIKE '%#RL#%' THEN 'Received L'
        END AS Short_code_detail
  FROM table_name
```

Comment: IF/ELSE is for flow control, i.e. you execute different SQL statements based on the result. It can't be used within a Select. `IIF` could be used, but it's just limited proprietary T-SQL syntax compared to Standard SQL CASE

Comment: What is wrong about your current query?

Comment: this query is taking a longer time.

Comment: The actual query is probably more complex, are you sure it's this tiny CASE causing long runtime?

Comment: Yes, this query is working on 3 lakhs rows, and the size of the description column is 4000 (like varchar(4000)). that's why it is taking approx 10 min to execute.

Comment: Between IIF and CASE WHEN it's down to personal preference.  The interpreter converts IIF to CASE WHEN.   IIF requires at least 1 "ELSE" condition but otherwise they're functionally the same.  Your query leaves off "ELSE NULL" but that's what happens if no TRUE value is met by the WHEN conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the query looks like with IIF instead of CASE WHEN.  The only difference is IIF requires the final ELSE condition (in this case the 3rd parameter of the last IIF is "NULL")

```
SELECT
       [ID]
      ,[DECRIPTION]
      ,iif(DECRIPTION LIKE '%#WR#%', 'Wrong Routine',
           iif(DECRIPTION LIKE '%#RB#%', 'Received Band',
           iif(DECRIPTION LIKE '%#WA#%', 'Week A',
           iif(DECRIPTION LIKE '%#CP#%', 'Change P',
           iif(DECRIPTION LIKE '%#BQ#%', 'Bad Q',
           iif(DECRIPTION LIKE '%#RL#%', 'Received L', NULL)))))) AS Short_code_detail
  FROM table_name
```

Comment: @HimanshuChauhan . . . `CASE` is generally preferred over `IIF()`.  It is standard SQL and more versatile.

Comment: @GordonLinoff why more versatile?

Comment: . . You don't need to nest it.

Comment: That's true but I'm thinking it wasn't always true because I remember using END END END END... back in the day.  IIF is shorter and I'm in a mad rush (because you answer questions before I can read them) so I use it :)

Comment: . . It has always been true.  People can misuse the construct, of course, but `case` in SQL -- and in other computer languages -- always allows multiple conditions.  (Well, someone will probably come up with a counterexample, somewhere.)

Comment: Ha, it's very possible I was doing it wrong.  With CASE WHEN I detest that you can leave off ELSE.  That's a flaw imo.  Maybe I'll switch to CASE WHEN for SO because you say it's preferred but I'll never leave off the ELSE

Comment: . . Interesting.  I remember once being bothered by leaving off the `else`.  That probably has to do with the `switch` statement in C and "falling through".  That said, I know appreciate that the default is `NULL` and that I don't have to do the extra typing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no if and else in SQL and CASE is used to implement the same, the nearset option you can get is IIF in sql server.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)